# RESTful API / HTTP Requests for MySQL

Tags: mysql, rest, http

I'm a little new working with databases, so I decided to give myself a simple project to begin with but I'm running into some issues.

Here's a breakdown of what I'm trying to accomplish:

1) Using MySQL, create a very basic table and store some information in it.

2) Connect to MySQL using Node and perform queries to print information to the console.

3) Then, access database information using a REST API (I only want to perform GET requests right now).

I've been able to do steps 1 and 2, but I cannot figure out how to do 3. Is it possible to perform these requests on MySQL data or should I go another route?

Comment: If you are using Node then why not use some framework like Express and then you can choose the ORM like waterline where you can define the modal and have the controllers to return the data based on the modal. And of-course you can write down your own routes `var router = require('express').Router(); router.route('/users') .get(appControllers.users.getAll);` of-course you need to have some middle wire to load the controller on appControllers usign fs module. There are many examples available for this.

Comment: I'll take another look at Express and try to find some examples to guide me. Thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: Here is a tutorial, http://www.nodewiz.biz/nodejs-rest-api-with-mysql-and-express/ , here they have call back for the routes and have written the logic there. For starting this is good, however if you use some good ORM over express its better to have the business logic in the controller , say your controllers are in the folder `controller` then you should have a middlewire to tell where to look before hitting the end routers

Comment: something as `var normalizedPath = __dirname + '/controllers/',
  appControllers = {}; fs.readdirSync(normalizedPath).forEach(function(file) {
  appControllers[file.replace('.js', '')] = require(normalizedPath + file)(app, config);
 });`
And then use `router.route('/users') .get(appControllers.users.getAll);` where `getAll` is the function name inside the controller `controllers/users.js`

Comment: I was able to make GET requests to my database! Thanks a lot!